# Split matrix into several depending on value in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix, split

I have a cell array that I need to split into several matrices so that I can take the sum of subsets of the data. This is a sample of what I have:

```
A = {'M00.300', '1644.07';...
     'M00.300', '9745.42'; ...
     'M00.300', '2232.88'; ...
     'M00.600', '13180.82'; ...
     'M00.600', '2755.19'; ...
     'M00.600', '15800.38'; ...
     'M00.900', '18088.11'; ...
     'M00.900', '1666.61'};
```

I want the sum of the second columns for each of 'M00.300', 'M00.600', and 'M00.900'. For example, to correspond to 'M00.300' I would want 1644.07 + 9745.42 + 2232.88.

I don't want to just hard code it because each data set is different, so I need the code to work for different size cell arrays.

I'm not sure of the best way to do this, I was going to begin by looping through A and comparing the strings in the first column and creating matrices within that loop, but that sounded messy and not efficient.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: So you want to group the data by the first column (ie. M00.x00) and then select the Nth element of each group and sum them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic use of [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).  You would use the first column as an index and the second column as the values associated with each index.  `accumarray` works where you group values that belong to the same index together and you apply a function to those values.  In your case, you'd use the default behaviour and `sum` things together.

However, you'll need to convert the first column into numeric labels.  The third output of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) will help you do this.  You'll also need to convert the second column into a numeric array and so [`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) is a perfect way to do this.

Without further ado:

```
[val,~,id] = unique(A(:,1)); %// Get unique values and indices
out = accumarray(id, str2double(A(:,2))); %// Aggregate the groups and sum

format long g; %// For better display of precision
T = table(val, out) %// Display on a nice table
```

I get this:

```
>> T = table(val, out)

T = 

       val         out   
    _________    ________

    'M00.300'    13622.37
    'M00.600'    31736.39
    'M00.900'    19754.72
```

---

The above uses the [`table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) class that is available from R2013b and onwards.  If you don't have this, you can perhaps use a `for` loop and print out each cell and value separately:

```
for idx = 1 : numel(out)
    fprintf('%s: %f\n', val{idx}, out(idx));
end
```

We get:

```
M00.300: 13622.370000
M00.600: 31736.390000
M00.900: 19754.720000
```

Comment: ah nice one. You beat me to it. Was just starting to write accumarray.

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you! I wasn't familiar with accumarray before; this did exactly what I needed much more eloquently than my other attempts

Comment: @KellyThomas You're very welcome :) `accumarray` is a very beautiful function - one of my favourites.  I do encourage you to learn more about it if you have the time.  Your question is one of the best use cases for it.  This is a nice gentle introduction to the topic: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/02/20/under-appreciated-accumarray/ - Good luck!